# Satisfy Composer platform dependency using alternative path

Tags: composer-php

How can I satisfy a Composer platform package dependency with an alternative path? I have a package that depends on `php >=5.4`, but my stock PHP is 5.3 and I have a separately maintained PHP 5.4 installation under the executable name of `php54`. Any way to make Composer aware of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run composer through your php54 executable. Either call it explicitly `php54 composer.phar ...` but that is painful if you have composer installed globally. In that case you're probably better off doing a shell script called composer that will call the phar file with php54 or register a bash alias for it.

Comment: Interesting workaround for this particular case. I actually solved it by symlinking my PHP 5.4 to a location higher up in my PATH, effectively making my default PHP 5.4, which makes sense since I need it for development anyway. Thanks!